Are there limitations in a SELECT statement when writing a pivot query
I'm trying to write a pivot query against a SQL Server database, and SQLQuery is complaining about the syntax (background: I have a working pivot query that uses a different table, and I'm trying to make a version for a new table).
I've been reading articles about pivot queries and searching for limitations on the SELECT portion, and I haven't found an explanation yet. The error message I get is that I'm using invalid column names, but if I just run a SELECT query without the pivot portion, then it works.
I have a table Centers with these columns:
Centers_RiskID (varchar(21), not null)
Centers_Change_Number (smallint, not null)
Centers_Center_Code (varchar(5), not null)
Centers_Change_Indicator (bit, not null)

The query that fails is:
SELECT
    Centers_RiskID, Centers_Change_Number, Centers_Center_Code
FROM
    Centers
PIVOT
    (MAX(Centers_Change_Number) 
     FOR [Centers_Center_Code] IN ([APP], [HQ], [MSFT])) AS pivot_table1

Centers_Change_Number and Centers_Center_Code on the first line are flagged as illegal column names.
But if I take off the pivot statement, then this query works.
SELECT 
    Centers_RiskID, Centers_Change_Number, Centers_Center_Code
FROM
    Centers

I'm using the SQLQuery app to test the queries.

after you pivot you have columns called [APP], [HQ], [MSFT] in the pivoted result, no longer a column called Centers_Center_Code

What values would you expect the columns (Centers_Change_Number and Centers_Center_Code) to contain when you're pivoting? For example, in the results in this db<>fiddle, what should be the value for Centers_Change_Number for 'def'? 456? 789? Something else?

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

From what I understand the SELECT statement should reference the columns after the pivoting operation has been applied
SELECT Centers_RiskID, [APP], [HQ], [MSFT]
FROM (
  SELECT Centers_RiskID, Centers_Center_Code, Centers_Change_Number
  FROM Centers
) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
  MAX(Centers_Change_Number)
  FOR Centers_Center_Code IN ([APP], [HQ], [MSFT])
) AS pivot_table1;

This is a helpful resource Link

Note: It is often not clear to the beginner that columns typically need to be limited at the source (prior to the PIVOT operation) to just those needed in the desired result. This is because PIVOT will effectively GROUP BY all columns present in the source, excluding the selector and aggregated value columns, even if those columns are not referenced in the final select list. See this db<>fiddle that demonstrates this behavior.
